# Temperature discrepancies in modelica fluid sources

Tags: modelica, dymola, simulationx

My goal is to model a bidirectional fluid system in Modelica. I have everything up and running using modelica standard library components but I am always getting an error on the fluid temperature from the input value.

I am trying to use a volume from the modelica standard library as a source but when i set the input temperature to 20C i always get a reading from a sensor directly after it at 19.87C. I know it's not a massive discrepancy, but I want to confirm I have not set up the problem incorrectly. I am using standard water as my medium.

I tried to simplify the problem and have just a source and a sink with a pump to move the water in one direction. No matter how simple a system i make I always get this error on the temperature. I tried changing the temperature both higher and lower on the source and sinks, but I always get the same error (0.07%).

Any way to fix it or any reference to categorise this as a numerical approximation/solver tolerance issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code (including graphical annotations). That makes it much easier to help you.